# LAN is not working, Showing "Cable Unplugged"

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, lan

I am using Lenovo B490 laptop and everything was fine. Few days back My friend used my laptop in my absence and after that I am not able to connect internet through the LAN port. It is showing that "Cable Unplugged" in the network manager. WiFi is working fine. And LAN is also working in the Windows OS, i checked it, becuase I am using Dual boot. The lights in the LAN port of the Laptop is working throughout booting, but once the desktop window is loaded the lights are going off. Any one can suggest what is the problem and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Vinga the same problem on a lenovo y700. I think that the auto-negotiation part is now working well.
In windows, all the cables work, under linux, only with one I can connect easily.

Comment: It would seem someone solved it with https://forum.teksyndicate.com/t/ubuntu-gnome-cable-unplugged-solved/78400 but this didn't worked out for me.